# Print keys and values from hash in a proper format?

Tags: perl, hash

Hello I am trying to print the values and keys of a hash with one key/value per row like this:

key:value

This is the code I am using to print my hash:

```
foreach (sort keys %hash) { print "$_:$hash{$_}\n"; }
```

And this is the output I get:

```
key
:value
```

Why is my script printing the value on a new row and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: Does the key have a newline character in it?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash` is much easier.

Comment: I'm getting the same type of output with that module. My key is just a word like example: "firstkey".

Comment: Are you sure? Show the code that populates the hash.

Comment: Or `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;` to make Dumper escape special characters, so newline will show as `\n`

Comment: my hash gets populated through two arrays: @hash{array1} = @array2

Comment: @NinjaAnte — Try editing the question to include [a proper test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't just dump code in comments where it is hard to read.

Comment: @NinjaAnte — That code isn't helpful. Telling us that it came from "an array" tells us nothing about what the values actually are.

Comment: Array1 contains keys like "abcxyz" and Array2 contains values like "123789", I'm not sure what kind of information you're looking for since I only just recently got into perl, sorry.

Comment: @NinjaAnte — As I said, try providing a test case that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Re "Array1 contains keys like `"abcxyz"`", Not quite. It contains a key like `"abcxyz\n"`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this version of printing loop:

```
foreach (sort keys %hash) {
   my $v = $hash{$_};
   s/\s+$//;
   print "$_:$v\n";
}
```

Keys in %hash definitely have some unwanted trailing characters, so it is better to filter them out when %hash is filled. For example instead of this:

```
@hash{@keys} = @vals;
```

Write this:

```
@hash{map { s/\s+$//; $_ } @keys} = @vals;
```

Or this:

```
chmop(@keys);
@hash{@keys} = @vals;
```

But `chomp` will not help with multiple characters.

Comment: Even better, remove the whitespace from the key strings before putting them into the hash.

Comment: This is not a great solution. If the OP tries to do anything else with the hash (check for the existence of a key, set a value, etc.), he will be confuzzled by strange bugs ("What do you mean key `foo` doesn't exist, I saw it in my `print` output!"). The correct answer is to remove the trailing whitespace at the source, before creating the hash.

Comment: The array that contains the keys for the hash is populated by a textfile containing various names with one name per row, There is no whitespaces in it, i've checked everywhere.

Comment: Are you `chomp`ing when you read it? Because that's very likely the root of your problem.

Comment: @NinjaAnte, Check again, because there is whitespace. Specifically, there's a linefeed.

Comment: Ah, "chomping" the key-array with a foreach-loop solved this particular problem.

Comment: You could simply do `chomp(@keys);`, but I'd chomp even sooner.

Answer (score 1):

The cursor is moving to the next line because your key contains a line feed. The solution is to remove the line feed from the key.

More specifically, you surely want to avoid creating a key with a line feed in the first place, so it should be removed from the key before you create the hash element.

You're presumably reading the key from a file handle. It's customary to use `chomp` (to remove any trailing line feed) or `s/\s+/z//` (to remove any trailing whitespace including line feeds).

```
my @keys;
while (<>) {
   chomp;         # Or: s/\s+\z//;
   push @keys, $_;
}

my %hash; @hash{@keys} = @values;
```